# how to delete cache programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to delete the cache files in my application programmatically.

How do i go about doing this in code?

I want to launch a service (which i already have set up to do this).

FYI - IDK why my acceptance rate is low. Ive accepted most or all of my answers.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200811/android-clear-cache-programmatically

Answer (score 7):

I assume you're talking about the Context's cache directory?

This is one way:

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();

if (files != null) {
    for (File file : files)
       file.delete();
}
```

Comment: Which part didn't work? (I use the same code in a few of my apps)

Comment: I have a cache directory called thumbnails inside of the Applications cache directory..I want it to delete everything in the cache

Comment: This only deletes the files in the root directly, you'll have to get a references to the directories too.