# activities lifecycle and how to cleanup temp files

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, temporary-files, resource-cleanup

I'm writing an app that allows the user to make a photo and then do some work with it.

I launch the camera with an IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, and provide a path to have the photo saved there.

This photo is temporary and I want to delete it when my app finishes.

I have an activity where I show the photo and allow the user to interact with it, and I thought the best way to delete it was on the onDestroy method.

The problem I am having is that when the user changes the orientation of the device, the activity is destroyed and replaced by a new one, but I cannot delete the file just because the user changes orientation as it is needed later on.

So, what can I do for keeping these files deleted?

Is there any other method i can overwrite, such as onAppExit, where I can delete all my temp files?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So declare global boolean rotation and use this :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    rotation=false;
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rotation = true;
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then in `onDestroy()` use

```
if(!rotation){
//delete here
}
```

Comment: it works fine, my files are not being deleted just because a orientation change. But also, the onDestroy is not being called. I will test this approach together with the onBackPressed suggestion by boulder.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to delete it in overrided onBackPressed() method of you activity. You see, back pressed event is the only exit point that means that user is done interactig with this activity instance and will newer return to it.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but if the application is finished while in another activity then the files will remain there

Comment: Yes, and they should remain since user can start you application again later and will be abble to navigate back to you activity. And if you delete this file, activity will be unable to find it.

Comment: Makes total sense, but I don't want these files to be there. If the app is restarted it should restart from the beginning (for the case of this app).

Comment: Are you using System.exit(0) in you application?

Comment: When what do you mean by "application is finished while in another activity"? How this can happen? User presses "Home" button? But in this case application isn't finished, it's just moved to background.

Comment: Do not use System.exit(0), it should not be used under most circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Always use [getExtExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29) API to get the cache directory on sdcard. Create all your temp files in this path. This cache will be destroyed after your app is uninstalled

Even better use [getCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) for cache dir path in local storage.. This memory will be automatically cleared when device is low on memory.

Here is a post that explains how to clear cache manually: [How to delete cache-folder of app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326852/how-to-delete-cache-folder-of-app)

Comment: Android documentation doesn't says this files will be destroyed on app exit. It says they will e destroyed on app uninstall

Comment: I am using that folder to create the files, but they remain there.

Comment: I started using getCacheDir, but as I recall, these files are private to your application, and the app interacts with others (sending the file as attachment by mail) which don't have visibility on that internal cache dir, so I changed to getExternalCacheDir.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `isFinishing()` method from within the `onDestroy()` as outlined in the accepted answer for this question [How to distinguish between orientation change and leaving application android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620841/how-to-distinguish-between-orientation-change-and-leaving-application-android)