# How to find and clear app cache?

Tags: android

---

I've read about using an LRUCache to cache bitmaps which are stored on the file system.the examples here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html.
Now I want to make a clearner app to delete cache of apps.I need to find cache of apps on android device.
I don't know how to do that.
Can anyone help me.
thanks

Comment: it depends on the device / operating system. Samsung, HTC, LG,... Which one do you have?

Comment: yes,my device is samsung

Comment: I misunderstood. I guess android doesn't allow an app to delete/empty caches of other apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18200934/4516895 -- this answer might be helpful.

Comment: Well in the link you provided you can see where the disk cache is made. In getExternalCacheDir or getCacheDir. If apps used  getExternalCacheDir then every other app can read and write those directories and hence delete files. Those directories look like /storage/sdcard/Android/data/<packagename>/cache

Comment: @Basil Miller:thank you.I will test it.

Comment: @greenapps :I will read getExternalCacheDir/getCacheDir and come back

Comment: No. Not getCacheDir(). That brings nothing. Those dirs are private to apps.