# Map raises cache in App-Info

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

I have a ViewPager with three tabs. In one tab is a googleMapFragment and when I add a marker the cache in the App-Info (Settings) rises. Also when I restart the phone the cache is still high. When I switch between the tabs nothing happens to the cache, only when I have added a marker.

Please could anybody tell me what this cache in the App-Info is and why my App caches all the markers added to the map?

Comment: How do you know the cache raised? Post a `screenshot` may help to explain the problem better.

Comment: I check the cache section in the app-info in the settings before I start the app and also after closing it. Then the cache raised.

Comment: You don't wanna it raised? I think because os save your map markers in caches, so that user can retrieve it quickly.

Comment: Is it a problem that it raises? Is there a limit where the OS decides to clear this cache?

Comment: I don't think it a problem and os don't clear until user does. Take look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5744208/4186942)

Comment: Ok. But if the cache is unlimited there are very much wasted MBs after some time.

Comment: I don't think it will take too much memory. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200811/android-clear-cache-programmatically) to `clear cache programmatically`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Clear cache programmatically doesn´t work, because the cacheDirectory is empty. 
I didn´t noticed any other problems except of the high cache.
Hope that it will not become to high. One time it was already about 30MB and is still rising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed above, to sum up:

The cache is basically a temporary storage area for an application while it's running -- it can store things like temporary images downloaded from the internet. Clearing it shouldn't really have much of an effect from a user perspective.

I think because os save your map markers in caches, so that user can retrieve it quickly.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744208/4186942) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069679/4186942).